# adding keylistener into java. implement keylistener class restriction?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, keylistener

i am trying to get this rectangle to move when i press the "w" key.  i was wondering why eclipse is giving me an error saying variable "hello" not found, whenever i clearly marked it as a declared rectangle above, and is it in a "public void" class.  when i press "w" it does nothing.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;    
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.*;

public class drawingComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(new Color(255,25,0));
        g2.setFont(new Font("monospace", Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC, 30));
        g2.drawString("nothing yet",300,320);
        Rectangle hello = new Rectangle(300, 100, 50, 50);          
        g2.fill(hello);
    }       

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {            
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){                
             hello.setLocation(hello.x-50, hello.y);                 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {        

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable hello is declared in the method `paintComponent()`. You need to make it a member of the class to make it available for the other methods, in short.

Comment: Also, what is up with all the empty lines? It makes it hard to read your code.

Comment: great, thanks , answered my question.  wonder why when i press "w" nothing seems to happen still?

Comment: @wilkers: Is it the `keyTyped()` method you want to invoke? That one contains nothing so nothing would happen. See [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/) and [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) for more information on how to use Graphics2D. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it answered your initial question.